# Problem using scale_size in R from library ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, geom

I am working with the library gapminder and I have generated the following graph to show the relationship between life expentancy, continent and gdp

```
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <-gapminder

ggplot(db1 %>% filter(year==2007), aes(x=pop, y=gdpPercap, color=continent))+
  geom_point()+scale_size(df$lifeExp)
```

However, the resulting dots are all the same size and I don't know why. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the size aesthetic before you can manipulate it using `scale_size()`, e.g.

```r
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

gapminder %>%
  filter(year == 2007) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = pop, y = gdpPercap, color = continent, size = lifeExp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size(name = "Life Expectancy (years)")
```

[image]

You can't really see the different size dots, but it's clearer if you log transform the x axis:

```r
gapminder %>%
  filter(year == 2007) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = pop, y = gdpPercap, color = continent, size = lifeExp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size(name = "Life Expectancy (years)") +
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Does that answer your question, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way for me to remove the life expectancy legend?

Comment: You can substitute `guides(size = "none") +` for the line `scale_size(name = "Life Expectancy (years)") +` to remove the life expectancy legend completely